# Knockout.js validation on hidden fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am implementing knockout validation for my form, and I want to make a field required only if it is showing. Depending on the selection of other fields in the form, some controls may be hidden by visibility:hidden or display:none. How can I make these fields required only if shown? I have tried this

```
var name = ko.observable().extend({
        required: {
            onlyIf: function () {
                return ($('#name').is(':visible'));
            },
            message: '*** Required'
        }
    });
```

But it doesn't seem to work, and I'm not sure if it should (can you write custom logic like that in knockout onlyIf params?).

Thanks for any help.

Comment: one way would be you should set visibility  `self.nameVisible=ko.observbale() to true/false` based on observable in viewModel later you can use the same observable in `.extend` with `onlyIf` . dynamic nature is maintained

Comment: I guess I did not put enough information. My fields are actually being shown/hidden based on information pulled from the database on page load AS WELL AS the selection of other controls. Nonetheless, your comment showed me how to approach it and I was able to solve. If you would like to make this an answer, I would be happy to select it.

Comment: thought of adding a fiddle nevertheless you got yourself a working one . added as answer, help yourself . cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments all you need to do is

Declare a observable in ViewModel per say `self.nameVisible=ko.observbale()` set the value it `True/False` from anywhere (either from DB or based on other control selection) . Later on you should use the `self.nameVisible()` in your validations i.e with `.extend` & `onlyIf` combo to make things(hide/show element+dynamic conditional validation) work .

**Html:**

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value:name,visible:nameVisible"/>
```

**viewModel:**

```
var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.nameVisible = ko.observable(true); //Set it dynamically 
    self.name = ko.observable().extend({
        required: {
            message: '*** Required',
            onlyIf: self.nameVisible
        }
    });
};
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```